# Interaction between components of 2 forms

Tags: c#, winforms

At first i disable a Toolstrip menu item so that when a user click the "Enable" button, the Toolstrip menu item can be enablem like:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem QLKHTSM;
```

The QLKHTSM is disable on the forms.

The problem is the Enable button is on the other form, so i tried to interact between 2 forms by this code(under the same form of that ToolStripMenuItem)

```
public static void enabletoolstrip()
    {
        QLKHTSM.enable = true;
    }
```

but the problem is with static, the QLKHTSM is unavailable, and without static, i can't call it in the other form.
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: cant you pass the `ToolStripMenuItem QLKHTSM` object to the form in which you want to enable/disable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the form where `QLKTHSM` is, Go to be Properties of `QLKTHSM` and change the Modifier property to `Public`. Then go to the second form and use.

```
public void enabletoolstrip()
{
    FirstForm f1 = (FirstForm)Application.OpenForms["FirstForm"];
    f1.QLKHTSM.Enabled = true;
}
```

If the form with `QLKHTSM` is not yet shown then you can create a global object.

```
FirstForm f1 = new FirstForm();
```

Then in your enable tool strip

```
public void enabletoolstrip()
{
    f1.QLKHTSM.Enabled = true;
}
```

Then wherever you want to show the form you use

```
f1.Show();
```

Comment: Thank you, it reports no error at first. But when i tried to debug it, it determined that the QLKHTSM is NULL before calling the method. I'm trying to fix it here, but still have no idea.

Comment: @user3032547 Is the form where `QLKHTSM` is present opened?

Comment: actually, yes and no. The second form, where that "enable" button present is a Log-in screen, it appear before the main form, where that QLKHSTM present. I'm using ShowDialog(), so it wont appear before a log in method is chosen.

Comment: @user3032547 Will a user click the enable button before clicking the button to go the next form?

Comment: The user can choose "enable" or not to go to the next form, but if one clicks "enable", the toolstrip menu should be enable. If a user click on "cancel", the next form will still show up, but with that toolstrip menu greyed out.